# Docker: Permission Error When Copying Google Service Account File

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I am having so much trouble reading in a gcp service account file in my docker container - it's basically saying I don't have permissions to read in the file. I literally spent all day trying to figure out this irritating issue and I just can't seem to resolve it.

Here's the error message I am getting stating permission denied:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 186, in 
_get_explicit_environ_credentials     os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS]   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 100, in 
load_credentials_from_file     with io.open(filename, "r") as file_obj: PermissionError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'secrets/logging-key.json'
```

Here is my docker file - I copied the service account file in the secrets folder

```
FROM python:3.7

LABEL maintainer='rihun@cisco.com'

RUN mkdir /myfiles
COPY . /myfiles

RUN chmod a+x /myfiles

WORKDIR /myfiles

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

ENV PORT 8080

EXPOSE 8080
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 -w 4 manage:app
```

I'm trying to establish google-cloud-logging, and this is when I run into the issue:

```
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging import Client
import logging
google_logging_client = Client.from_service_account_json("secrets/logging-service-account-file.json")
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You seem to run the chmod only on the directory. Don't know if you meant to, but try adding the -R flag to recursively update the entire directory structure. If that is not it, what is the absolute path of your file? Make sure it is there and you can get there relateively (as in, from the /myfiles workdir).

Comment: That's the solution!